# Nodejs - Data is getting inserted but I am not getting the response back

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am using mysql with Nodejs and my requirement is to check whether an user exists or not and if user doesn't we should create that user.

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var phone = req.body.phone;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var datecreated = req.body.datecreated;
    var dateupdated = req.body.dateupdated;

    db.query("select * from users where name='" + name + "' and password='" + password + "'", (error, rows) => {
        if (error) {
            res.send({ "status": "failure", "Error": error });
        }
        else if (rows.length > 0) {
            res.send({ "status": "exists" });
        }
        else {
            db.query("insert into users(name, password, phone, datecreated, dateupdated) values('" + name + "', '" + password + "', '" + phone + "', '" + datecreated + "', '" + dateupdated + "')"), (error, rows) => {
                if (error) {
                    res.send({ "status": "failure", "Error": error });
                }
                else {
                    res.send({ "status": "success" });
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here if an user exists I am getting the response as status, but if **I send new user the data is getting Inserted but I am not getting the response**. Need some help guys.

**Working Solution:**

```
db.query("select * from users where name='" + name + "' and password='" + password + "'", (error, rows) => {
        if (error) {
            res.send({ "status": "failure", "Error": error });
        }
        else if (rows.length > 0) {
            res.send({ "status": "exists" });
        }
        else {
            db.query("insert into users(name, password, phone, datecreated, dateupdated) values('" + name + "', '" + password + "', '" + phone + "', '" + datecreated + "', '" + dateupdated + "')", (error, rows) => {
                if (error) {
                    res.send({ "status": "failure", "Error": error });
                    res.end();
                }
                else {
                    res.send({ "status": "success" });
                    res.end();
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't past the solution into your question. Either create an answer with your solution (if no other answer exists that provides the solution or if you have a - in you opinion - more complete solution), or accept an existing answer that provides the solution.

Comment: ok sure @t.niese

Comment: The `res.end()` should not make any difference, what version of express and mysql modules do you use?

Comment: I am using express 4.16.3 and nodejs 8.11.3

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this code.
If no error is found the number of rows are sent using the `send()` method. When another query is successful another `send()` method is invoked but that won't work because `send()` ends the connection after sending the data. You can run `send()` only once as when a connection is closed other `send()` won't work. Instead use `res.write()`, which don't close the connection themselves. `send()` internally implements `res.write()` immediately followed by `res.end()`

```
if (error) {
            res.send({ "status": "failure", "Error": error });
        }
        else if (rows.length > 0) {
            res.send({ "status": "exists" });
        }
        else {
            db.query("insert into users(name, password, phone, datecreated, dateupdated) values('" + name + "', '" + password + "', '" + phone + "', '" + datecreated + "', '" + dateupdated + "')"), (error, rows) => {
                if (error) {
                    res.send({ "status": "failure", "Error": error });
                }
                else {
                    res.send({ "status": "success" });
                }
            }
```

The code should be

```
  if (error) {
            res.write({ "status": "failure", "Error": error });
        }
        else if (rows.length > 0) {
            res.write({ "status": "exists" });
        }
        else {
            db.query("insert into users(name, password, phone, datecreated, dateupdated) values('" + name + "', '" + password + "', '" + phone + "', '" + datecreated + "', '" + dateupdated + "')"), (error, rows) => {
                if (error) {
                    res.write({ "status": "failure", "Error": error });
                    res.end()
                }
                else {
                    res.write({ "status": "success" });
                    res.end()
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks the fix worked, but need one more fix too I closed second db.query before itself. Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: If this helped you upvote and mark it as correct so it can help other too

Comment: The callbacks of `db.query(` will only be called once, and the `res.send` are all separated by `if - else if - else` blocks. In what situation would the function `res.send` be called twice? The response ` res.write({ "status": "failure", "Error": error })` does not have a matching `end`, and even if your claim would be right then sending two json encoded strings concatenated does not make any sense.

Comment: Where? If  `if (error) {` evaluates to true then `res.send({ "status": "failure", "Error": error })` and nothing more is done. If there is no error and `else if (rows.length > 0)` is true then `res.send({ "status": "exists" })` is called and nothing more is done. If `rows.length` is `0`, then `else {` applies, and the `insert` query is done. And that callback you only have a `if - else` block so there is no way that `res.send` might be called twice for one request.